# Rails + Devise -> clearing session cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, session-cookies, warden

I got a situation like this:

using Rails 4 + Devise

I log out user, during that I got my chrome developer tools opened and check in Network what headers are flying around. The thing that interests me is "sign_out" (action/cookie? i don know the exact name I should use here).

In it's request header i got a session variable "_app_name_session".

If I copy this variable and make a GET request to some part of my site that requires an user to be authenticated then I get 200 OK response (although I have already logged out!)

How could I prevent this from happening?

I have already tried a `Warden` callback in my `User` model like this:

```
Warden::Manager.before_logout do |user, auth, opts|
  auth.cookies.delete :_app_name_session
end
```

and

```
Warden::Manager.before_logout do |user, auth, opts|
  auth.cookies["_app_name_session"] = ""
end
```

but this doesn't work and the session variable is set anyway in the cookies.

Is it possible to timeout session immediately upon logout?

This really bothers me as although the session should be cleared upon logout but it is not and there is a way (I know, complicated and attacker would have to get through other security layers) to hijack user session.

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3031   upon reading this link I see that this is kinda trade-off of using cookie-based sessions. The suggestion there was to move to different storage. Are there any good strategies on how to do this?

Comment: Like you've noticed, this is just the core limitation of client-side sessions. Rails makes it very easy to switch session storage; check out the README for a gem such as https://github.com/roidrage/redis-session-store for instructions.

Comment: I've hoped that it could be adjusted somehow. Thanks for the reply. Will read more about database session storage